# Can't run multiple instances of backstretch

Tags: jquery, css

when I try to add two different background to two different div or on the body and a div, only one of the two is displayed.

Like this page : http://geek1983.no-ip.org/caro_new/

The background is displayed, but not the #sliders div.

P.s. You can see the javascript on the bottom of the code.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the setup directions on the Backstretch website. I didn't even see any call for the Backstretch script to fire.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

You need to add this in your head tags.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.backstretch([
      "link-to-image.jpg"
    , "link-to-second-image.jpg"
    , "link-to-third-image.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: You didn't saw the backstrech call? I wrote on my post that the scripts ares on the bottom of the page.

/* Set an image as a fullscreen wallpaper */
$.backstretch("images/background.jpg");
$("#slider").backstretch("images/caroline.jpg");